# Watermark fails to show on image when using the imageresizer and WicBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

I am looking to use [imageresizer](http://imageresizing.net/) for image and text overlays.

However when I use the WicBuilder plugin and the watermark plugin together the watermark specified in the query string no longer shows.

I cannot see anything in the documentation about limitations when using the WicBuilder. Is this supported or a known issue?

Comment: Watermark perhaps embedded in the alpha channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In V3.X, WicEncoder and WicDecoder can work with Watermark, but not WicBuilder or FreeImageBuilder. WicBuilder is an alternate rendering pipeline that sacrifices a small amount of quality and some flexibility in exchange for a large speed increase.